# Missing Operator in a `for` loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax-error

I've started to write a brainfuck compiler in bash.
The 'compiler' translates the code in assambly to compile it using `gcc`.
The problem is, when I try to run it, it prints this error:

```
$ ./compiler test.bf
./compiler: Zeile 111: src: {0..45}: Syntax Fehler: Operator erwartet. (Fehlerverursachendes Zeichen ist \"{0..45}\").
```

(In english:

```
$ ./compiler test.bf
./compiler: Line 111: src: {0..45}: Syntax Error: Operator excepted. (Causal Error Char is \"{0..45}\").
```

)

As I might understand, It says that there is a fault in line 111:

```
...
for i in {0..${#src}}        # line 109
do                           # line 110
    case ${src:$i:1} in      # line 111
...
```

(Here is the full [code](https://github.com/caffeinated-fox/tau/blob/master/compiler))

But I don't see any.

If the error is cause of the for loop, can you tell me how to make a for loop like in python:

```
for i in range(15):
    ...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the C-style `for` loop:

```
for ((i=0; i < ${#src}; i++)); do
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped a lot ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables inside the `{m..n}` construct ; use `seq` instead :

```
for i in $(seq 0 ${#src})# line 109
do                       # line 110
    case ${src:$i:1} in  # line 111
```